# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: java, ms-access, insert-into

I decided to add an "Add" button where Employee records are added to my Access Database, Employee table.

Whenever I clicked the "Add" button, an error message shows up saying "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement". Can anybody help? Is there something wrong with my coding? Cause I really followed this video exactly, even though in the video, the person managed to successfully "Saved" the records to the database and I keep getting errors.

```
conn = Connect.ConnectDB();
        String sql = "insert into Employee ("
                +"Employee ID,"
                +"Employee Name,"
                +"Employee NICN,"
                +"Employee Gender,"
                +"Employee Contact Number,"
                +"Employee Department)"
                +"values("+txteid.getText()+ ",'"+txtename.getText()+"','"+txtenicn.getText()+"','"+txtegender.getText()+"','"+txtecnumber.getText()+"','"
                +txtedept.getText()+"')";
        try{
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Added");

        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
```

Comment: this is the video, that i referred to: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqXtWlzwKM4

Comment: Given that this code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, I would strongly advise you to find a different source of information.

Comment: Looking at the video, the author doesn't appear to follow Java naming conventions, either. I strongly advise that you read a decent book or tutorial on JDBC rather than learning anything from this.

Comment: Can you printout the sql-string and try it in a console?

Comment: Sure there was no underscore instead of space in the column names? `Employee_ID` etc,

Answer (score 1):

You use prepared statement so you must work with parameter

```
   conn = getConnection();
   String sql = "insert into Employee ("
                +"Employee ID,"
                +"Employee Name,"
                +"Employee NICN,"
                +"Employee Gender,"
                +"Employee Contact Number,"
                +"Employee Department)"
                +"values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

And then set the parameter:

```
      pstmt.setInt(1, txteid.getText()); // set input parameter 1
      pstmt.setString(2, txtename.getText()); // set input parameter 2
 ...
      pstmt.executeUpdate(); // execute insert statement
```

Comment: Column names that contain spaces will also have to be enclosed in square brackets, e.g., `[Employee ID]`.